# How to use zlib library in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017, zlib

I want to use the **zlib** library in my c++ project. So, I have downloaded [zlib](https://www.bruot.org/hp/libraries/) library(**zlib_1_2_8_msvc2015_64.zip**).
Then, I have created zlib folder under `"C:\Program Files\Zlib"`. Then, Extract **zlib_1_2_8_msvc2015_64.zip** file into `"C:\Program Files\Zlib"`.

After that, I have opened **visual studio 2017** and goes to **property** => **C/C++** => **general** => **additional include directories** and 
added that path : `"C:\Program Files\Zlib\msvc2015_64"`.

After that, I have added `#include <zlib.h>` header file in my project. but, not working.

So, How to use zlib library in visual studio 2017?

Comment: Does `zlib.h` present in that path `C:\Program Files\Zlib\msvc2015_64`? Right-Click on that include statement and ask it open the file, it would throw an error showing all the folders where it looked for while trying to open the file.. make sure your path is there in it

Answer (score 4):

For static library installation , include the zlibstatic.lib and directories in the linker additional libraries and directories. For dynamic library , include the zlib.lib in the linker and copy the zlib.dll to the project output directory.

Another option is to install vcpkg ( MS packager to install windows based open source projects) and use powershell command like so `.\vcpkg install zlib:x64-windows-static`. The zlib can be auto integrated to your project using `.\vcpkg integrate install`

Answer (score 2):

You have specified where to find the header files.

You also need to find which library to bind and where to find it.

For Visual Studio 2012:

In linker section -> General -> additional library directories, you can specify the path where the library resides

In linker section -> Input -> additional dependancy , you can specify the actual lib name to bind

Answer (score -2):

Its a simple fix copy all contents of msvc2015_64 directory into zlib directory and you are good to go.

Comment: Is it possible to be more precise about which directories to copy from and to? Such as full paths (in the default case), and maybe an explanation of why this is the correct approach.

Comment: I assume that your visual studio is unable to detect zlib packages from system. By default vc tries to look for files in C:\Program Files\Zlib or C:\Program Files(x86)\Zlib in my case when I putted contents of msvc2015_64 directory (which were available in zlib_1_2_8_msvc2015_64.zip file) into C:\Program Files(x86)\Zlib directory it worked.

Comment: If visual studio is still finding some files missing i would recommend to download and install https://excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/zlib/1.2.3/zlib-1.2.3.exe and then copy from C:\Program Files(x86)\GnuWin32 and paste into C:\Program Files(x86)\Zlib (if folder does not exists create one and put it into that.)