# C++ zlibstatic library in VS2019

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm in the process of learning C++ and I'm halfway through one of my courses so I figured I would try to do something to challenge myself and I'm getting stuck on what I'm trying to do. Long story short I'm trying to parse some info from a file inside of a zip folder.

I followed this post here to understand what to do but I'm missing something that is not quite ovvious to me: [How to use zlib library in visual studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505546/how-to-use-zlib-library-in-visual-studio-2017?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I'm using VS2019
I researched the libzip and zlib libraries online and realized that I need to get the zlibstatic.lib into my project. I've read through the above posts and I thought I set my paths and folders correctly, but I'm getting an error not being able to source the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meXfb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkOx0.png)

Thanks for any advice in advance! I hope everyone is staying safe!

Cheers!

MattG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can see that there is no file called `zlib.h` in the directory you specified. I don't know zlib but usually the header files are in a searate directory. Often it's called include something or other.

Bottom line, in the 'Additional Include Directories' setting you need to specify the folder containing zlib.h, not zlibstatic.lib.

I'm guessing you will also need to add zlibstatic.lib to the Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies setting. It's not enough just to specify the directory where the library is, you have to name it as well.

Comment: Hey John! Thank you for the response, and yes, I completely overlooked that I was looking in the wrong file path, whoops! this seems to be happier now! Thank you again!